# Array list duplication in java

Tags: java

I have an array list of String element I want to duplicate last element of that list and that duplicate element set in the 0th position of same list. how to duplicate array list.

below is my input list:

```
List ["Apple","Tomato","Patato","Brinjal","Cabbage"]
```

I want below type of list as output:

```
List ["Cabbage","Apple","Tomato","Patato","Brinjal","Cabbage"]
```

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
    cars.add("Apple");
    cars.add("Tomato");
    cars.add("Patato");
    cars.add("Cabbage");
    System.out.println(cars);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try cars.add(0, cars.get(cars.size() - 1))

Comment: Question, why are you adding foods to a list called `cars`? Just curious.

Comment: Really oddly named cars?

Comment: Did you search? Did you look through [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html)? Did you try something?

Comment: Note: Doing something like `cars.add(0, cars.get(cars.size() - 1))` will work, but that makes the first and last element the same instance; this may be okay for an immutable object like instances of `String`, but for mutable objects this could lead to unintended side effects.

Comment: @Slaw Correct. On the other hand having two object representing the same car could lead to other undesirable results, such as inconsistent updates. The choice needs to taken based on the particular situation, and in some situations there is no perfect solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
    cars.add("Apple");
    cars.add("Tomato");
    cars.add("Patato");
    cars.add("Cabbage");

    // Geting the last element of the list
    String lastElement = cars.get(cars.size() - 1);

    // Adding the last element to the starting of the list
    cars.add(0, lastElement);

    System.out.println(cars);  // This should out put your expected result.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you specify needing a *copy* of the list, you might add the last element to an empty `ArrayList<String>` then use `addAll` to add the original list elements.

```
ArrayList<String> copiedArraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
copiedArraylist.add(cars.get(cars.size()-1);
copiedArraylist.addAll(1, cars);
```